# Why is Crystal .should be producing a spurious error

Tags: crystal-lang

I am converting a Ruby program to Crystal as I learn it.

Here is an error message I am getting:

```
# Error
Failures:
  1) Test Rule class can return the name property
     Failure/Error: rule.name.should be "RpsIphone"

       Expected: "RpsIphone" (object_id: 4504126256)
            got: "RpsIphone" (object_id: 4524981536)

     # spec/rule_spec.cr:11
```

And here is the code that is causing it

```
# from spec
rule.name.should be "RpsIphone"
```

I also checked that the two strings when compared with .same? also say they are not the same. I've looked at those 9 characters over and over. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

- Crystal's `.should be` tests for the objects being the same,
  identical, same object_id
- Crystal's `.should eq` tests for the values being the same

Comment: The `object_id` is a dead giveaway. Equivalent in Ruby: `"RpsIphone".equal?("RpsIphone")` says `false`